# import packagename.* not working

Tags: java, package, javac

I have written the following code:

```
package abc.def;

public class test {

public void test() {}
public void disp() {
 System.out.println("in disp");
}

}
```

then I used following command to compile:

```
javac -d . test.java
```

it works fine, but when I tried to import the class "test" using "import abc.def.*" it does not import test class, the code is :

```
import abc.def.*;


public class checktest {

 public static void main(String a[]) {

 test t = new test();

}

}
```

following error is generated:

```
D:\javaprograms>javac  checktest.java
checktest.java:8: cannot access test
bad class file: .\test.java
file does not contain class test
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpa
th.
 test t = new test();
 ^
1 error
```

Comment: You need to point javac to the class file (test.class, wherever that was generated).

Comment: can you provide me the exact syntax of javac in this case

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem.

No additional classpath is required to set.

According to your scenario, your working directory might contains test.java file. You can just remove the test.java file from the working directory and compile using javac checktest.java.

It will work.

Thanks.
Britto

Answer (score 1):

Did you make the proper directory structure? You need to have the test.java file in abc/def if that's the package name you want.

You can also point to the compiled test.class file with -cp flag

Example:

> javac -cp test checktest

Comment: the directory abc/def already contains test.class, further i copied test.java in same folder too, but problem not solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your directory structure should look like this:

- current working directory

  - checktest.java
  - abc

    - def

      - test.java

Then, from the directory on the top, you can compile checktest:

```
  javac checktest.java
```

This will automatically find (and compile) test.java too. If you only want to compile test, do it this way:

```
  javac abc/def/test.java
```

Then all the class files will be in the right directories, too.

Comment: the directory structure is correct as specified. I think classpath variable is not set correctly, what should be the exact path, as my "test.java" is in d:\javaprograms\abc\def\test.java and "checktest.java" is in "d:\javaprograms" and "d:\javaprograms" is my current directory

Comment: "import abc.def.test" is working correct but "import abc.def.*" does not work

Comment: Your CLASSPATH variable should not be set at all. If you want to make sure it is ignored, use `javac -cp . checktest.java`.

Comment: @imran: I just tried your program (with the directory structure lined out in my answer), and it compiled without any problems. Maybe your file system makes some problems? At least, when compiling this way your output should be not the one in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have by mistake compiled test.java  in the topmost directory itself, therefore the JVM is picking test.class from the top most directory and also from abc\def\test.class hence conflict is happening.

please type: ls test* in the top most directory and confirm if that is the case and delete this extra test.class and then recompile.

Answer (score -1):

**first know this**  - To use the package in other programs, compile the .java files as usual and then move the resulting .class files into the appropriate subdirectory of one of the directories referenced in your CLASSPATH environment variable.

For instance if /home/name/classes is in your CLASSPATH and your package is called package1, then you would make a directory called package1 in /home/name/classes and then put all the .class files in the package in /home/name/classes/package1.

Now suppose your classpath is /home/name/classes then compile

```
package abc.def;

public class test {

public void test() {} public void disp() { System.out.println("in disp"); }

}
```

using `$ javac -d /home/name/classes test.java`

Now put this code

```
import abc.def.*;

public class checktest {

public static void main(String a[]) {

test t = new test();

}

}
```

inside the folder

Comment: when i write "import abc.def.test" it works fine, only "import abc.def.*" creates problem.